# Examples of filters over the natural numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples, filters

Given a set $X$, we can define a filter $F \subseteq 2^{X}$ (here $2^{X}$ means the powerset of $X$) as a family of sets that have the following properties:

(i) $F \not= \emptyset$

(ii) If $S_{1}, S_{2} \in F$ then $S_{1} \cap S_{2} \in F$

(iii) If $S_{1} \subseteq S_{2} \subseteq X$ and $S_{1} \in F$ then $S_{2} \in F$

I'm having a hard time coming up with filters over the natural numbers, we saw one example in the book which is called the Frechet filter defined as $F = \{S \in 2^{\mathbb{N}} : S^{c} \text{ is finite}\}$ Here $S^{c}$ means $\mathbb{N} \setminus S$. It's easy to see that this is a filter using properties of sets, but I can't come up with any other filter over the natural numbers, it just seems so abstract.

Comment: Choose any $A \subseteq \Bbb N$.  Then $F_A= \{ S \subseteq \Bbb N \mid A \subseteq S \}$ is a filter.  If $\vert A \vert =1$, then $F_A$ is an ultrafilter, called a principal ultrafilter.

Comment: The powerset itself is a filter. The intersection of filters is a filter. In particular, given any collection of subsets of $X$, there exists a least filter that includes the collection, by considering the intersection of all filters that include the given collection.

Comment: Take a sequence $(m_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of natural numbers and define$$\mathcal{F}=\left\{A\subset\mathbb{N}\,:\,(\exists N\in\mathbb{N})\text{ such that }n\ge N\implies m_n\in A\right\}.$$

Comment: @RobertShore Would you mind elaborating a little on why does it  become an ultrafilter when the cardinality of the set is 1?

Comment: An ultrafilter is a filter $F$ such that for every subset $B$ of $X$, either $B$ or $B^c$ lies in $F$. If $A$ has cardinality $1$, then $F_A$ satisfies the condition.

Comment: (Addendum: an ultrafilter is a filter, *different from $P(X)$*, such that...)

Comment: As for the abstractness, just think of $S\in F$ as saying that $S$ is "large" in some sense; the filter defines the precise sense of "large". Very likely you have read about ultraproducts (or are about to), where given $f,g\in\prod A_i$, we declare $f\equiv g$ if $\{i:f_i=g_i\}\in F$. So if $f$ and $g$ agree at a "large" number of places, then they are equivalent.

Comment: I like to think of a filter as corresponding to a "for sufficiently *foobar* $x$, $\varphi$" type of quantifier.  Here $\varphi$ is a formula, with $x$ possibly a free variable in it, which corresponds to a subset of the domain of discourse, and the truth value of the quantified formula corresponds to whether that subset is in $F$.  So for example, the statement "for sufficiently large $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $| \frac{\sin n}{n} | < \frac{1}{100}$" would amount to saying that $\{ n \in \mathbb{N} \mid |\frac{\sin n}{n}|<\frac{1}{100} \}$ is in a "largeness" filter.

Comment: F = { S ⊆ ℕ | 1∈S} is a filter on  ℕ This lets us make many filters, just take any natural number, and consider the subsets of  ℕ which contain it. This procedure can be generalized to make a filter on any nonempty set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A classical silly example is a principal (ultra)filter for a point $p \in \mathbb{N}$, i.e. the filter of the form
$$
F_p = \left\{ S \subseteq \mathbb{N} : p \in S \right\} .
$$
More generally, if $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is any subset of $\mathbb{N}$, then you can define the filter
$$\left\{ S \subseteq \mathbb{N} : A \subseteq S \right\}.$$
Another silly example would be the power set of $\mathbb{N}$, which is the special case of the previous example you get when you take $A = \emptyset$.

Another way of constructing filters is this: If you have a filter $F$ and some $E \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that $E, E^\complement \not \in F$, then you can look at the filter
$$F \cup \left\{ S \cup E : S \in F \right\} ,$$
which you can think of as the filter you get when you take $F$ and append $E$ to it.

EDIT: My last section about $F \cup \left\{ S \cup E : S \in F \right\}$ is not, I don't think, true in general. Thank you to @Andreas Blass whose prodding prompted me to revisit this. There is, in general, a way to talk about a filter "generated by" some set $\mathcal{H} \subseteq 2^X$. Write
$$\mathcal{F}^\mathcal{H} = \left\{ A : \exists B_1, \ldots, B_n \in \mathcal{H} \; \left( A \supseteq B_1 \cap \cdots \cap B_n \right) \right\} .$$

You can check that this defines a filter, and that $\mathcal{F}^\mathcal{H} \supseteq \mathcal{H}$. Less obvious, but still elementary to check, is that this is the *smallest* filter that contains $\mathcal{H}$. This ties into another construction of filters: If $\mathscr{F}$ is some family of filters on $X$, then $\bigcap_{F \in \mathscr{F}} F$ is also a filter on $X$ (take this as an exercise). You can check that if $\mathscr{F}^\mathcal{H}$ denotes the family of all filters on $X$ that contain $\mathcal{H}$, then $\mathcal{F}^\mathcal{H} = \bigcap_{F \in \mathscr{F}^\mathcal{H}} F$. Here's a quick sketch of the proof: On one hand, if $F \in \mathscr{F}^\mathcal{H}$, then $\mathcal{F}^\mathcal{H} \subseteq F$, so $\mathcal{F}^\mathcal{H} \subseteq \bigcap_{F \in \mathscr{F}^\mathcal{H}} F$. In the other direction, we can see that $\mathcal{F}^\mathcal{H} \in \mathscr{F}^\mathcal{H}$, so $\mathcal{F}^\mathcal{H} \supseteq \bigcap_{F \in \mathscr{F}^\mathcal{H}} F$.

Comment: In your last example, $S\cup E$ should presumably  be $S\cap E$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I don't think so. I'm trying to write the filter generated by $S \cup \{E\}$.

Comment: With $S\cup E$, your filter won't contain $E$ unless $F$ already contained $E$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Hence why I have the $F$ in that expression. I believe $F$ is a filter in the OP.

Comment: How is having $F$ in the expression supposed to put $E$ into your filter?

Comment: @AndreasBlass thank you for your prodding. I've revised my answer in light of it.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of other examples: Define the *density* of a subset $A\subseteq\mathbb N$ to be the limit of $\displaystyle{\frac{|A\cap\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}|}n}$ as $n\to\infty$ (provided the limit exists). Then the sets $A$ of density $1$ constitute a filter.

The sets $A\subseteq\mathbb N$ for which $\sum_{n\notin A}\frac1n$ converges form a  filter.

Once you've seen these examples, you can probably produce plenty of similar ones.